# How to recover dropped table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I dropped my table Departments I don't know how its happened and I can't roll it back

[image]

I really really need it back please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its not a big problem you can try one of these    :

```
flashback table departments to before drop;
```

or

```
select * from user_recyclebin;
flashback table "BIN$...." to before drop;
```

Note that you can rollback DML(`insert, update, delete` ...) but not DDL(`create, DROP`...)

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

use FlashBack Query

flashback table departments to before drop;